# jQuery .each function outputs value from previous each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need help with some of my code I did.

I am using a .each function to get values from an div like the ID and also an aria-label that has a class ".snappy".

For the most part I've been kind of able to get it to work minus the output of the looped items.

Here is my jQuery Code.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
  var snappyLabel = "";
  var snappyID = "";
  var snappyList = "";
  $(".snappy").each(function () {
    // Test if the div element is empty
    snappyLabel += $(this).attr("aria-label");
    snappyID += $(this).attr("id");

    snappyList +=
      '<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#' +
      snappyID +
      '"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">' +
      snappyLabel +
      "</div></a></li>";

    return snappyList;
  });
  console.log(snappyList);

  $("body").append(
    '<div class="sidenavcontainer"><ul class="sidenavwrap">' +
      snappyList +
      "</ul></div>"
  );
});
```

the output of the above is this

```html
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#intro"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Intro</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#introautomotive"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">IntroAutomotive Tinting</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#introautomotivehometinting"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">IntroAutomotive TintingHome Tinting</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#introautomotivehometintingcommercial"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">IntroAutomotive TintingHome TintingCommercial Tinting</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#introautomotivehometintingcommercialppf"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">IntroAutomotive TintingHome TintingCommercial TintingPaint Protection Film Clear Bra</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#introautomotivehometintingcommercialppfceramic"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">IntroAutomotive TintingHome TintingCommercial TintingPaint Protection Film Clear BraCeramic Coatings</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#introautomotivehometintingcommercialppfceramicgraphicwraps"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">IntroAutomotive TintingHome TintingCommercial TintingPaint Protection Film Clear BraCeramic CoatingsGraphics Vehicle Wraps </div></a></li>
```

When it should be like this

```html
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#intro"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Intro</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#automotive"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Automotive Tinting</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#ppf"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Paint Protection Film</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#hometinting"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Home Window Tinting</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#commercial"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Commercial Window Films</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#ceramic"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Ceramic Coatings</div></a></li>
<li class="sidenavitem"><a class="navitem" href="#graphicwraps"><div class="sidenavicon"></div><div class="sidenavtitle">Wraps</div></a></li>
```

as you can see the last value keeps adding to the next value "I.e: #introautomotivehometintingcommercialppfceramicgraphicwraps"

I think it has to do with the `+=` in the `.each` function but I am not entirely sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To prevent appending `snappyLabel` and `snappyId` to each `<li>`. You'll need to replace `+=` to `=`

```js
    snappyLabel += $(this).attr("aria-label");
    snappyID += $(this).attr("id");
```

```js
    snappyLabel = $(this).attr("aria-label");
    snappyID = $(this).attr("id");
```

Comment: so I did that but it only returns one output when there are multiple elements with class snappy. maybe I shouldn't use each function? loop?

Comment: So i was able to get this to work with slight modifications. I appended the container before the each loop, and then within the each loop I appended the li elements with your suggestions. I appreciate it